# Detecting Lines in Data

Tags: fitting, data, machine-learning

I have some data representing a vaguely periodic signal, here is a sample

```
signal = Flatten[
   Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tomginsberg/3dd708afa51dc4300ad4a50b24a0b3bf/raw/8903014fc7a71bb430d3435e7fc3c5e36bec0281/signal.txt", "Data"]];

ListPlot[signal, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ImageSize -> Full, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image]

My only knowledge about the data us that it should contain several increasing lines of similar slope and several areas of noise. I went through the first bit by hand and selected windows where lines occur then ran a linear regression to get this

```
(* Indexed signal *)
isig = Transpose[{Range[Length[signal]], signal}];
f[{a_, b_}] := isig[[a ;; b]]

(* Fits in pre determined windows *)
fits = (Fit[#1, {1, x}, x] &) /@ 
   f /@ Partition[{1, 194, 1779, 1846, 1935, 2182, 2178, 2425, 2490, 
      2600}, 2];

Show[ListPlot[signal[[;; 2600]], AspectRatio -> 1/10, 
  ImageSize -> Full], 
 Plot[fits, {x, 0, 3000}, PlotRange -> {0, 248}, PlotStyle -> {Thick},
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]]
```

[image]

What I want is some automated way to come up with the windows where all the points in the window approximately follow a line. Then I can do regression on the windows and the problem is solved.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreaciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use `Differences@signal` to identify large changes (e.g. > +/- 200) in successive values to locate the windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea here is to use a `GradientFilter` on the accumulated signal and spot the maxima using `MaxDetect`. This creates a run of 1's when the signal gains momentum in a straight line towards the peaks, and we can find positions of those 1's and split when there's a jump in the position > 1.

```
acmg = Rescale[GradientFilter[Accumulate@signal, 1]];
mdacmg = MaxDetect[acmg, .85];
ListLinePlot[{mdacmg, acmg}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]
windows = #[[{1, -1}]] & /@ Split[Flatten[Position[mdacmg, 1]], #2 - #1 == 1 &];

Show[
 With[{max = Max[signal]},
  Graphics[{Gray, Rectangle[{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[2]], max}] & /@ windows}]
  ],
 ListLinePlot[signal, PlotStyle -> Red]
]

(* resulting windows to check for fit:
 {{8, 185}, {351, 361}, {1128, 1165}, {1265, 1690}, {1729, 1941},
 {1975, 2181}, {2216, 2441}, {2483, 2639}, {2764, 2917}, {2982, 3630},
 {3803, 3935}, {4123, 4304}, {4367, 5585},
 {5616, 5870}, {5897, 6164}, {6193, 6404}} *)
```

[image: runs]

Comment: thanks that work quite well, I added an extra flag that only excepts windows if the $r^2$ value of the fit is high enough (say > .9)

Comment: is `GradientFilter[Accumulate@signal, 1]` not essentially the identity?

Comment: @user2757771 no - that would be `Differences[Accumulate[signal]]`. The `GradientFilter` with radius 1 is wider and more smooth - the result of `GradientFilter[Accumulate@signal, 1]` is very different from the original signal.

Comment: I see `GradientFilter[Accumulate[{a, b, c, d, e, f}], 1] // Simplify` returns `{Abs[b]/2, 1/2 Abs[b + c], 1/2 Abs[c + d], 1/2 Abs[d + e], 
 1/2 Abs[e + f], Abs[f]/2}`. So a slightly smoothed version. The output is still nearly identical if you run `ListLinePlot[{Rescale@signal, acmg}]` to compare.

Comment: If the smoothing bothers you, just remove it, or use a mean filter instead.